# Beginner: SDK manager fails, Eclipse fails to load ADT

Tags: android

I can run the emulator from the command prompt and start it from the desktop (Win7 32-bit) using a batch file, but it doesn't run from the SDK Manager.

Also, I have installed Eclipse, but when I try to load the ADT Plugin, it seems to run then I get

"Cannot complete install because one or more required items cannot be found"

I've tried changing https to http. No difference. If I cancel any of the ticks beside the list of 4 installation components, the "Next" box is no longer greyed out.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try the [Android ADT plugin installation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two different parttions such as a C drive and a D drive? or have you migrated your user profile to another drive? If so that's your issue

Comment: No, it's a standard Win7 installation with just the hidden boot area and the C: drive. I have not migrated the user profile anywhere - just have the standard user profile as originally installed. It's a Lenovo G550 laptop set up to emulate non technical user installations for audio software and hardware testing.